# Include additional library files used for compilation, but only for a single file?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a node project which includes some javascript that is meant to run in a browser. Currently I'm expressing these javascript functions as strings since expressing them as pure javascript functions will trigger several compile time errors. The logic behind this being "javascript that targets browsers is considered an 'external platform', and therefore it's reasonable to express this code as a string", similar to how OpenGL Shader code gets embedded into C++ project as strings.

I'm hesitant to do any of the following:

1. Adding [the `"dom"` types to the `"lib"` section of my project's tsconfig](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) as my project is not meant to be a browser-based project.
2. Adding an additional nested tsconfig for that one file.
3. Ignoring compile time warnings in that section of the project.
4. Rolling my own minimal types for the types I'm using, including the relevant attributes/method calls.

Is there a way to include the `"dom"` libs in a single file, perhaps with an inline (or header) comment of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

This is very old, but for anyone else who's interested you can do something like:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts" />
```

This must be the very first line in the file (no newlines before it).

I should state clearly that these types will also show up in all files that import this file (they're infectious).